# What's the right mathematical operation to determine the probability of an event when you know the population size and sample probability?

Tags: probability

I'm a tad rusty with math but I don't think this is too hard yet I am struggling.

There are 50 beings in a dungeon. 5% of them have superhuman strength. Of the ones that do

- 3% are elves
- 35% are dwarves
- 62% are orcs

How can you determine the probability that an elf you encounter in the dungeon has superhuman strength? Unfortunately you can't ask them because some of them are dark elves who would like nothing more than to deceive an adventurer.

One more thing, sorry:

- 10 of the beings are elves
- 20 are dwarves
- 20 are orcs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem):

$P(Strength \mid Elf) = \cfrac{P(Elf \mid Strength) P(Strength)}{P(Elf)} = \cfrac{(.03)(.05)}{P(Elf)} $

We don't have enough information to solve this problem because we aren't given the probability that a creature in this dungeon is an elf. Also, I find it rather odd that $2.5$ beings in this dungeon have superhuman strength, and thus exactly $.075$ elves have such strength. Kind of a bunk problem?

Comment: Yeah you're right it is. It's a stand-in for a more controversial question and I might not have made all the substitutions correctly. I added more information. Thank you for your answer so far.

Comment: Wait sorry, when I read your answer the first time I was on my phone and didn't see that you had basically given me everything I needed. Can you confirm? After my last comment I added that 10 of the creatures were elves (so a 20% chance). Plugging the rest in I get (.03*.05)/.2=.75%. Does that look good to you?

Comment: Then $P(Elf) = .2$, not $.02$

Comment: Typo, thanks. Fixed it.