# Is this an okay way to calculate covid-19 death rates?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm a tad rusty on my math skills but this isn't too hard. Can you confirm that I am doing this right.

I wanted to know what percent of people die from covid-19 so I started looking for statistics. To my surprise the [CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/cases-updates/cases-in-us.html), the [WHO](https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019), and [Google](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02o5TthCyq0HyB_27TyhvwHb8rg6w%3A1589147953574&ei=MXm4XuvHIuOf_Qafk4PgBA&q=coronavirus%20statistics&oq=coronavirus%20statistics&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQR1CBKliBKmCkKmgAcAF4AIABAIgBAJIBAJgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwirpJK6parpAhXjT98KHZ_JAEwQ4dUDCAs&uact=5) publish statistics:

[image]

But then I found [this](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/368/6490/489) article in Science which says that 86% of all infections go undocumented. To adjust for that I do:

```
(total)(1-.86)=confirmed
total = confirmed/.14
```

Which works out to:

[image]

Then I wanted to see how that works out by age. To my surprise (again) the CDC has an awesome tool for that (Thank you CDC!). [Here's a link to the tool](https://data.cdc.gov/d/9bhg-hcku/visualization). I can't link to my results because you have to login to save your search and I don't want to mess with that right now.

Anyways I created the following report:

```
Dimension: Age Group
Measure: COVID-19 Deaths
Filters:
    From 2/1/2020-5/10/2020
    Sex (Male and Female)
```

[And the results are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSVVe.jpg):

[image]

Which for the particular date range that I selected amounts to 87,116 deaths. If you transform that into what percent of people are dying by age you get:

[image]

Next, I used the [Census information for 2019](https://www.census.gov/data/tables/2019/demo/age-and-sex/2019-age-sex-composition.html) to get what percent each age range is of the total U.S. population (super lucky the age ranges matched up!!!):

[image]

So right off the bat you can see it has a massively disproportionate effect on older folks ([interesting graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeFfs.jpg)). The last thing then is to figure out what the odds are of dying from covid-19 for each age range. I had to get some [help](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3668893/whats-the-right-mathematical-operation-to-determine-the-probability-of-an-event) for this part. I think I have all the numbers plugged in right. It just uses Bayes' Theorem (which sadly I never studied):

```
*using 35-44 as example:
P(age range death rate | population death rate) = (age range death rate)(population death rate) / P(age range) = (.016)(.0097)/.126 = .0012 = .12%
```

Filling out the rest of the table the death rates by age are:

[image]

I would be much obliged if you could check that the mathematical operations that I performed support the conclusions I drew in my final table. Especially if you could double check that I used Bayes' Theorem the right way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that stick out to me in your methods.
First, the article you are referencing is referring to undocumented infections in *China*.

> Here, to assess the full epidemic potential of SARS-CoV-2, we use a model-inference framework to estimate the contagiousness and proportion of undocumented infections in China during the weeks before and after the shutdown of travel in and out of Wuhan.

The conclusion of this study found that before any travel restrictions were put in place, about 86% of all infections were undocumented. Specifically, this statistic was found looking at infections "before the 23 January 2020 travel restrictions." Looking at the model, they looked at 375 Chinese cities. Since this was asked in May 2020, I am going to assume that these numbers were cases and deaths globally. Regardless, I would be wary on using such a study to find the true number of cases globally since the scope of the study was in China during a specific time frame.

---

Second, if we assume the 86% statistic is appropriate to use, you do calculate the "true" number of cases correctly, but there is much variability here. Stylistically, I would have truncated my decimals instead of rounding up. For example, for the cases pertaining to the WHO:
$$\frac{1}{0.14}(3,925,815)=28,041,535.71 \rightarrow 28,041,535$$
Granted, that's not really going to change much; however, the big issue I see here is that you re-scale the number of cases to some true amount, but you do nothing with the number of deaths. Basically, if we look at the WHO for example, we go from almost 4 million cases to around 28 million cases, but the number of deaths remains identical. This is a huge issue and makes your death rate *severely* inflated to the point where it's useless.

---

Now, let's look at your age analysis. As I stated earlier, you never adjusted the death toll when you adjusted the total number of cases, but it seems you are solely looking at deaths of these age groups. With that in mind, you're not using your readjusted values for total cases at all (at least with *this* analysis), so it will have no impact here. 
Age ranges look good and your calculations look correct. Grouping into $<5$ years is good, I was going to mention how the first few age ranges were so low. Using census data to get American proportions is fine -- I personally would have tried to find data for American COVID cases only; however, I am not sure how readily available that data was at the time. This is a good alternative. 
You say there massively disproportionate effect on older folks, but your graph is honestly difficult to read. I'm sure you were in the works of developing visualizations, but it would be much easier to read with appropriate axes and labels. My question is why are you showing "deaths by age range," which is considering the global death count for those age groups, alongside "percent of pop...," which is considering the death percentage of the American population. It's not necessarily wrong to show these two on the same graph, but it would be more helpful to look at deaths by age range in America and the death percentage by age range in America. Also, is deaths by age range the number of deaths? If you really want these on the same graph, you should have two y-axes since you have proportions and numbers. Though, if you want to emphasize percentages independently, you can use a pie chart. Personally, I would have shown these visualizations independently on two separate graphs.

---

**Assuming your values are correct,** if you want to find the odds of dying from COVID-19 for each age range, your idea looks correct. Given the population death rate, what is the probability of death in that age range? When we interpret this, we need to explicitly state that this probability is only true when we look at deaths from 2/1/2020-5/10/2020.

---

I understand that this was asked some time ago, but if anyone comes across this in the future, hopefully they can take some ideas from this analysis. Overall, there are great ideas here. We just need to go about them carefully.